# How is 'Any CPU' implemented?

Tags: .net, winapi, assemblies, reverse-engineering

How is 'Any CPU' implemented on low level?

Aren't there two formats: PE32 and PE64? Both Windows x86 and x64 can run 32-bit. But, it's not made by having a 64-bit executable inside the 32-bit and run it in memory, because then the process will have a different ID than the starter. So how did they do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In his [argument against Any CPU](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/09/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx), Rick Byers also includes some background information that is relevant to this question:

> Since we wanted people to be able to write .NET libraries that they could re-use from both 32-bit and 64-bit processes, **we worked with Windows to extend the OS loader support to enable architecture-neutral ("AnyCPU") PE files.**

Check the link above for more detailed information.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But does that mean AnyCpu works only for .NET apps? Can it be used from unmanaged language?

Comment: @blez: As you may know, managed code is JIT compiled at runtime. In the case of the 'Any CPU' target, the .NET JIT compiler may choose to generate 32-bit or 64-bit specific bytecode. Unmanaged code, on the other hand, is compiled directly to platform specific bytecode at compile time. As a result, unmanaged binaries are directly tied to a platform and cannot be compiled for a generic "Any CPU" platform.

Comment: I already know that. But can I create an empty AnyCPU executable that runs without .NET installed?

Comment: I don't want to run any .NET code, it's for my JIT. I just want to run executable on both platforms.

Comment: @blez: I have no idea what you're talking about. What is your JIT?

Comment: Does every AnyCpu PE file require .NET CLR to load it, or Windows can run it without .NET. That's my question.

Comment: @blez: Managed binaries **require** .NET to run regardless of the platform (be it x86, x64, or Any CPU). You **cannot** produce unmanaged "Any CPU" type binaries.

Answer (score 1):

PE32 is extended for .NET. The platform flag just specifies where the executable is intended to run and can be changed with [CorFlags.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). This article has a good description of [the .NET File Format](http://ntcore.com/files/dotnetformat.htm).

Comment: So I can't create a empty AnyCPU executable that runs without .NET installed?

Comment: You need .NET redistributable package installed that includes .NET loader and .NET framework required to run a .NET application.